# How to generate scaffold RESTful view templates in Laravel like how RoR does?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-artisan, laravel-blade

Rails generates a folder of view template scaffolds when you run the cli command `rails g controller User`.

It will have view template scaffolding for create_user.html.erb, update_user.html.erb, list_user.html.erv....etc etc.

Is there anyway to have that same functionality in Laravel whether via a library, some included function, or a custom generator(or some other way)?

I'm using Laravel 5.4 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking to generate views, I assume you're talking about a CRUD admin panel rather than an API.  I highly recommend Laravel CRUD.

https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD

This will allow you to create a model, controller, all routes, views etc with the command `php artisan backpack:crud Model`.  It's super easy to use, but you'd want to probably start your project fresh - it assumes you're using it for the whole admin section, not just the views.